# How to update only email using devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to update only email using this form, but validation is failing `Current password can't be blank`, requires password_confirmation, I don't have a clue how to void this requirement

```
 <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => {:method => :put, :id=>"email_form"}) do |f| %>
            <%= devise_error_messages! %>
            <div><%= f.label :email %>
              <br/>
              <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>
            <div><%= f.submit "Update" %></div>
        <% end %>
```

**UPDATE**
This is my update action in the overrided controller RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def update
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)

    successfully_updated = if needs_password?(@user, params)
      @user.update_with_password(params[:user])
    else
      # remove the virtual current_password attribute update_without_password
      # doesn't know how to ignore it
      params[:user].delete(:current_password)
      @user.update_without_password(params[:user])
    end

    if successfully_updated
      set_flash_message :notice, :updated
      # Sign in the user bypassing validation in case his password changed
      sign_in @user, :bypass => true
      redirect_to after_update_path_for(@user)
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  private
  def needs_password?(user, params)
    user.email != params[:user][:email] ||
      params[:user][:password].present?
  end
end
```

Comment: is this already working for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just point to other controller than devise's own registration controntroller, with your own logic for this update action.

You can also override devise registration's controller (read devise docs).

Example:

```
# config/routes.rb
resource :profile     # Singular resource and profile 

# profiles_controller
def show
  # render your view with the for
end

def update
  current_user.update(params[:user]) # if rails < 4 use update_attributes instead
end

# _form.html.erb
<%= form_for(current_user, url: profile_path, html: { method: 'PUT' }) do |f| %>
  ...
```

For the second option, overriding devise's own registration controller, I don't really like this approach because in this case you are not really dealing with registrations but an already registered user account:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password

After your edit:

I see you are using the second option. Take a look a the **needs_password?** method in the controller

Comment: yes, i think the problem is in needs_password? method, it may needs some extra check